# calculation sum of cost for the full hour

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

based on the value in the table: timestamp, cost I would like to get the increment sum of cost value every hour.

Table:

| Timestamp | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-12 00:05:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-12 01:01:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-12 02:06:00 | 3 |
| 2021-01-12 03:01:00 | 3 |
| 2021-01-12 03:02:00 | 2 |

### The expected result:

| Timestamp | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-12 01:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-12 02:00:00 | 2 |
| 2021-01-12 03:00:00 | 5 |
| 2021-01-12 04:00:00 | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below version actually works!

```
select Timestamp,
  sum(price) over(order by Timestamp) price
from (
  select 
    timestamp_add(timestamp_trunc(Timestamp , hour), interval 1 hour) as Timestamp,
    sum(price) as price
  from `project.dataset.table` t
  group by Timestamp
)
```

if to apply to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` date truncated to hour and then use analytical function as follows:

```
select timestamp_trunc(Timestamp , HOUR) as tst,
       sum(sum(price)) over (order by timestamp_trunc(Timestamp , HOUR)) as price
  from your_table t
group by tst
order by tst
```